# Followup method for answered posts would be nice

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

For posts that have been answered, it would be nice to see a "Followup" section (just below the original question text section) where I can put a followup narrative about how I used the 'checked' answer to completely solve my issue.   Right now, if I want to post followup information I need to edit the original question and it doesn't look that nice when you do it that way.   Also, you could add badges for being a good user for following up and adding more info after the question is answered.

Comment: Self-answer sounds more appropriate, if you do not want to add it to the question.

Comment: obviously, self-answer wasn't the reason behind why stack overflow was created, and so i dont agree.

Comment: @djangofan: you are wrong about that! Self-answer is highly encouraged!

Answer (score 6):

I usually just put an **EDIT** block in as you mentioned.  I think this is a good way to do it, because many times there are multiple **EDIT**s to be added in as an issue is worked, and input given and received.

Comment: Yup, editing the question to put in additional information (separated with a horizontal rule) is easy and is also aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: I also use **UPDATE** as a marker that I've added something to the post (sometimes even with a date)

Comment: That sounds like a good way to do things.

Comment: what I am suggesting here is a feature that stack overflow lacks that might be nice. the concept of "followup" isn't currently "formally" handled in the workflow.